# Is there a way to use regexes in sed without having to put backslash everywhere?

Tags: sed

To use regex syntax in sed, you have to put in `\` before `(`, `{`, etc. to use them as special characters. For example:

```
~ > echo 123 | sed 's/[0-9]{2}/x/'
123
```

vs.

```
~ > echo 123 | sed 's/[0-9]\{2\}/x/'
x3
```

This is the reverse of what I'm used to. Is there any way to make characters have special meanings by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo 123 | sed -r 's/[0-9]{2}/x/'
```

Comment: In GNU sed - only - the '`-r`' option enables extended regular expressions, where the metacharacters have their meta-meaning unless preceded by a backslash, which is the reverse of the standard convention in 'sed'.

Answer (score 0):

If your `sed` doesn't have `-r`:

```
echo 123 | perl -pe 's/[0-9]{2}/x/'
```